# Drop functions and triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working with some very active tables, and wanted to create some triggers and functions. Do you know if DROP/CREATE operations are atomic and work with transactions? Do you thing that can be any locking risks when applied to those tables?

I tried looking in documentation and Stack Overflow, but no info specific to triggers and functions can found.

Comment: [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html): *Replacing an existing trigger within a transaction that has already performed updating actions on the trigger's table is not recommended. Trigger firing decisions, or portions of firing decisions, that have already been made will not be reconsidered, so the effects could be surprising.*

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, but this is only for replace, not for drop/create. I can't find specific info about this.

Answer (score 2):

All `CREATE` and `DROP` functions are fully transactional, so there cannot be any inconsistencies.

But you have to watch out for locks. Creating a trigger takes a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, and dropping a trigger takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table. That means that `CREATE TRIGGER` prevents concurrent data modifications on the table, and `DROP TRIGGER` prevents all concurrent access to the table. All locks are held until the end of the transaction.

If all your database transactions are short like they should be, these statements won't cause a problem. With long concurrent transactions on the affected tables, they will cause problems. Also, be careful about modifying more than a single table in one transaction: that can easily cause deadlocks with concurrent database activity.